# Executing multiple commands in init.d script

Tags: shell-script, init.d

I have the following init.d script:

```
#! /bin/sh                                                                                          
### BEGIN INIT INFO                                                                                 
# Provides:          Django-Server                                                                  
# Required-Start:    $all                                                                           
# Required-Stop:                                                                                    
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5                                                                        
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6                                                                          
# Short-Description: Django Server                                                                  
### END INIT INFO                                                                                   

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin                          

. /lib/init/vars.sh                                                                                 
. /lib/lsb/init-functions                                                                           
# If you need to source some other scripts, do it here                                              

case "$1" in                                                                                        
  start)                                                                                            
    log_begin_msg "Starting Django Server"                                                          
    python3 "/home/pi/Python Projects/episode_tracker/manage.py" runserver 0.0.0.0:12345  --insecure
    python3 "/home/pi/Python Projects/shifts_server/manage.py" runserver 0.0.0.0:23456  --insecure  
    log_end_msg $?                                                                                  
    exit 0                                                                                          
    ;;                                                                                              
  stop)                                                                                             
    log_begin_msg "Stopping Django Server"                                                          

    # do something to kill the service or cleanup or nothing                                        

    log_end_msg $?                                                                                  
    exit 0                                                                                          
    ;;                                                                                              
  *)                                                                                                
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/django_server {start|stop}"                                            
    exit 1                                                                                          
    ;;                                                                                              
esac
```

I'm aware that `stop` doesn't do anything useful at the moment.

My problem is with the lines:

```
python3 "/home/pi/Python Projects/episode_tracker/manage.py" runserver 0.0.0.0:12345  --insecure
python3 "/home/pi/Python Projects/shifts_server/manage.py" runserver 0.0.0.0:23456  --insecure
```

For some reason, only the first one is executed. If I comment the first one, then the second is executed (so the syntax is correct, the path exists etc).

If it matters, the OS is Raspbian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `manage.py runserver` command isn't forking off as a daemon and so the init script is sitting there waiting to finish.  You can put a `&` at the end of the two lines to make them both be backgrounded.

```
python3 "/home/pi/Python Projects/episode_tracker/manage.py" runserver 0.0.0.0:12345  --insecure &
python3 "/home/pi/Python Projects/shifts_server/manage.py" runserver 0.0.0.0:23456  --insecure &
```